# Branch.io link for iOS 9+ issues

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I used Branch.io for my project to launch app from my website. What I want is if app is off, when I click the universal link on web it will open HomePage first. In contrast, it opens another.  It works well with iOS 8. But in iOS 9+, it always open the LaunchScreen.

Please, take a look at my code:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let branch = Branch.getInstance()
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions) { (params, error) -> Void in
      DHIndicator.hide()
      if let _ = params {
        print("kdlkasdlf: \(params.debugDescription)")
        if let str = params["$deeplink_path"], url = NSURL(string: str as! String) {
          NSLog("link: \(url)")
          self.path = url.path
          self.query = url.query
          LaunchAppFlowManager.shareInstance.displayLaunchDetails()
        } else {
          // load your normal view
        }
      }
    }
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    AccountFlowManager.shareInstance.start()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(url)
    if AppDelegate.shareInstance().window?.rootViewController?.nibName != "LaunchScreenVC" {
      DHIndicator.show()
    }
    return true
  }

func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print(userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString)
    if AppDelegate.shareInstance().window?.rootViewController?.nibName != "LaunchScreenVC" {
      DHIndicator.show()
    }
    return Branch.getInstance().continueUserActivity(userActivity)
  }
```

And, func to start app:

```
if let _ = AppDelegate.shareInstance().path, _ = AppDelegate.shareInstance().query {
        let navi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomePageVC())
        self.navi = navi
        AppDelegate.shareInstance().window?.rootViewController = navi
      } else {
        let vc = LaunchScreenVC()
        AppDelegate.shareInstance().window?.rootViewController = vc
      }
```

Comment: Alex with Branch.io here: it sounds like Universal Links may not be completely configured in your app. Could we see an example link that you're using for testing? If you don't want to share that info publicly, feel free to [submit a support ticket](https://support.branch.io) instead!

Comment: Here are two test link: https://8obj.app.link/stream?$deeplink_path=onedoor://onedoor/stream?id=1/undefined and https://8obj.app.link/stream?$deeplink_path=onedoor://onedoor/stream?id=1/617c30ed70384800d838417b68d1e7ab. I also already submitted a ticket. So please check.

Comment: We'll take a look and get back to you. Thanks for the links!

Comment: @AlexBauer Please, check my email again.

Comment: I think I'm running into the same issue.  @AlexBauer would you be able to help?

Comment: Hi @Ben! Would you mind either posting a new question (I'll see it if you tag branch.io) or submitting a [support ticket](https://support.branch.io)? Much easier to debug if we can keep things separate :)

Comment: I finally found out the way to trick in my app. Thanks for your supports.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the issue:

1. On iOS 8, when a Branch Link is clicked the app opens and shows
   the correct ViewController
2. On iOS 9, when a Branch Link is
   clicked the app opens but the default ViewController is shown

The issue in this case is related to Universal Linking. Previously, using URI Schemes on iOS 8, you would route within your app using $deeplink_path. Rather than use $deeplink_path, with Universal Links Branch now recommends using link data stored in custom fields to inform in-app routing decisions, as described here: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method

Additionally, it is important to locate the code used for in-app routing within the Branch init completion block, as this completion block is only run after the response from Branch's servers have been received and the link parameters are available. If the code for in-app routing is located outside the completion block (and not called by the completion block), it is likely that the routing decision will be made before link parameters have actually been returned by Branch.